# How do I find the minimum SOP and POS of [ (XY)’ + (X’ + Y’)’Z ]?

Tags: digital-logic

I am a first year computer engineering student and my professor has a really thick accent, so it is hard to understand what he teaches. I'm just looking for clarification on how to do this problem.

Comment: Create a truth table and find an expression taking into account all 1s. It will be the SOP. For the POS, you can find an expression taking into account all 0s and then take the complement of the whole expression.

Comment: @jonk - Hi, Please remember that the site consensus on Meta was not to provide full answers to homework-type questions, with no effort shown by the OP. Also, answers in comments [aren't allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work). Thanks.

Comment: Quinn Conger - Welcome :-) Please [edit] your question, show your "working" and make it clear *exactly* where you are stuck. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can solve this problem by writing out the expression in its most basic sum-of-products or product-of-sums form, and then factoring out common expressions using basic algebra to get your minimized expression. You can also solve via Karnaugh maps.

There are some nice resources online which walk through the detailed instruction on how to do these steps, so I'll just point you to some rather than reproduce the material here. (These were all from a basic Google search, but I scanned the material and it all appears to be of good quality and should be helpful.)

- [MIT OpenCourseWare "Computation Structures" Section 4 "Combinational Logic"](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-004-computation-structures-spring-2017/c4/)
- [The video from that MIT OpenCourseWare course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1eIFnKOZ-oY) which walks through sum-of-products
- [A set of slides from Illinois Institute of Technology](https://www.iit.edu/sites/default/files/2021-02/kmaps.pdf) covering logic minimization, describing SOP and POS, and walking through Karnaugh maps.
- [Another video overview of SOP and POS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sdEZairzU-M)

If you're having trouble understanding your instructor, then I'd highly recommend you supplement your in-class instruction with this type of online material throughout the course. When you are a first-year student these types of resources will be plentiful -- enjoy it while it lasts!